# Config Tailwind in react native not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, tailwind-css, nativewind

i am new with react native and typescript.
in this project i want to use the tailwind css and follow instruction at nativewind to config **tailwind.config.js** like this

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.tsx",
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

but any file in the src not apply the css.

and if i config it like this

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.tsx",
    // "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    "./src/screens/Home.tsx",
    "./src/screens/MainLayout.tsx",
    "./src/screens/Profile.tsx",
    "./src/screens/Search.tsx",
    "./src/screens/SplashScreen.tsx",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

then its working, what have i done wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to **Aqeel Ahmad** i can fix this with **glob**

new config **tailwind.config.js** :

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const globSync = require('glob').sync;

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.tsx",
    ...globSync('./src/**/*.tsx'),
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear try this by apply css on each file based on extention

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
content: [
"./App.tsx",
"./src/**/*.tsx",
"./src/**/*.js",
"./src/**/*.ts",
"./src/**/*.jsx",
],
theme: {
 extend: {},
},
plugins: [],
}
```

Hope this will solve problem

Comment: thanks for the idea but its not work for me 

Comment: then you can try glob package to get all file at one place like:
import { glob, globSync } from 'glob'

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.tsx",
    ...glob.sync('./src/**/*.tsx'),
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}

Comment: thank you, its work fine for me when usingg glob, thank u for the idea