# I used nativewind this plugs, but it's only working app.js not working login.jsx, where has problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nativewind

I used nativewind this plugs, but it's only working app.js not working login.jsx, where has problem?

When I writed this code in app.js, it's working.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-white">
      <Text className="text-[40px] text-rose-500">Victoria</Text>
      <Text>CBD | GLEN T</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <LoginScreen />
    </View>
  );
}
```

But, when I tried to writed LoginScreen.jsx, the css isn't working.

```
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

export default function LoginScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image className="w-full h-[400px] object-cover" source={require('./../../assets/Victoria_logo.jpg')} />
      <Text className='font-bold text-rose-500'>Buy Beef</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I don't know why the Text className css isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your path in `tailwind.config.js` is not correct for other file like login or etc.

Just check my article how to configure `tailwind in react native` on below link:

[Tailwind CSS in React Native](https://medium.com/@aqeel_ahmad/tailwind-css-in-react-native-2024-ac4cc7973446)

or check my this answer on stack:
[Config Tailwind in react native not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78062213/config-tailwind-in-react-native-not-working/78062474?noredirect=1#comment137619303_78062474)

Hope it will help you.